# Ctrl + Alt + Delete WM message number

Tags: windows, security

Any one know what the windows procedure when press the keys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd>?
I ask about the windows procedure message number returned when you press those keys. I would like to know the number on all possible windows versions (w7, xp, vista, ...).

Comment: It depends on Windows version. Which one are you targetting ?

Comment: windows 7 do you know ????????

Comment: In the future, please ask your actual question instead of a question that you think will answer your actual question. Your actual question is "Can you disable Ctrl + Alt + delete in c# code using window procedure?"

Answer (score 2):

**Winlogon.exe** intercept the Secure Attention Sequence (SAS), wich is CTRL-ALT-DEL. It is a regular hotkey, registered with `RegisterHotKey`, but since Winlogon gets it first, you cannot steal it or disable it, in any programming language.

When Winlogon receives the SAS, it launches **LogonUI.exe**. LogonUI is the process that displays the "tiles", those squares you see on the logon screen. Each square is an implementation of a **Credential Provider**.

The credential provider collects your credential data, often a name and password. It sends back that information to Winlogon as an opaque array of bytes, along with the name of an **Authentication Package**.

The authentication package knows how to make sense of that array of bytes. I will use that information to log you in, maybe by getting a Kerberos ticket or checking your password againts a stored hash. If all checks out, it will give a security `TOKEN` representing your user to Winlogon.

Almost done.

Winlogon creates a new **Window Station**, with a **Desktop** named "Default". I will create the process identified by the **Userinit** registry key, usually userinit.exe (unless your computer is part of a botnet ;). That process runs with the token from the Authentication package.

Userinit performs some tasks, like creating your profile if this is your first logon ever. It will then launch your shell, usually **Explorer.exe** which will read various startup parameter, like all those unreadable icons next to the clock.

I've put the major mile stones **in bold**. I suggest you research the parts that interests so we can better help you by answering a more specific question.

Comment: can you disable Ctrl + Alt + delete in c# code using window procedure

Comment: It can't be done. The best you can do is make it happen automatically (there is a GPO named "Require users to type CTRL-ALT-DEL" or something similar). C# has nothing to do with it, its just how the security is implemented.

Answer (score 1):

I think winlogon is called from the raw input thread, I don't remember exactly how, maybe a event or LPC. The whole point of C.A.D. is that a normal program cannot intercept it.

You can try to emulate it on pre Vista systems with a custom GINA that calls [WlxSasNotify](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: can you disable Ctrl + Alt + delete in c# code using window procedure

Comment: @HassanShatnawi: No you probably need a kernel driver